# Azure service principal check his own password expiration date

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal

We have an application that has a service principal configured in order to grant access to azure resources. 
This service principal has a password configured with an expiration.

We want to configure our application to be aware of his service principal credential password expiration date.
Which is the best way to grant access to a service principal to his own expiration date?

By default this is not allowed.

```
az ad app show --id xxxxxxxxxx

Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

But can enable some API permissions *(legacy Azure Active Directory Graph /Directory.Read.All)* and it works but this seems too open.

Is there any way to to grant access to only see only data from his own application id? Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, seems you could not do that. At least you need to grant the `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission. The command `az ad app show --id xxxxxx` essentially calls the azure ad graph api, you could check with `--debug`.

[image]

To call this api, from least to most privileged, it needs `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`, `Application.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.Read.All`. In your case, `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` is not an option.

Besides, I also have tested `az ad signed-in-user show`, if you login with an AD App, it looks not to support to use this command.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative : Key vault secret expiry date can be used as an option to notify you about the expiry of the SP but the setup can involve significant effort.

While creating the SP, you specify the expiry period - 3 months, 6 months, 1 year etc.
After setting the expiry date, you set a key vault secret with the same expiry date.
Before the arrival of the expiry date, an event grid notification can trigger an Azure function to renew the secret.

For more details on key rotation using Key vault, Event Grid and Azure Functions, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation.