# Grant a service principal access to check password expiry of other apps (or own)

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform

I'm trying to use the least privilege approach. I know how to grant directory or app reader privilege, but that would open the whole AAD and I want to be more selective. I also figured that an owner of an app could do that, but that would also allow the principal to read and modify the passwords. Is it even possible to grant access to only read password expiry for specific app/service principal?

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "secret_checker_monitors_app_pwd_expiry" {
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.checker.object_id
  scope                = azuread_service_principal.another.object_id
}
```

I've tried this, but it complains about invalid scope. What would be the correct scope? I suppose some `/aad/scope/.../x-y-z-object-id`. What would be the correct role name? Or would I need a custom role? Which permission?

[Someone tried something similar here and concluded it was not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823773/azure-service-principal-check-his-own-password-expiration-date). Still hoping...

Answer (score 0):

[Use `azuread_app_role_assignment` instead](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/2.11.0/docs/resources/app_role_assignment):

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "secret_checker_monitors_app_pwd_expiry" {
  app_role_id         = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.app_role_ids["Application.Read.All"]
  principal_object_id = azuread_service_principal.checker.object_id
  resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.other.object_id
}
resource "azuread_service_principal" "msgraph" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph
  use_existing   = true
}
data "azuread_application_published_app_ids" "well_known" {}
```

The `azurerm_role_assignment` is for Azure resources. `azuread_app_role_assignment` was introduced in azuread provider 2.4.